# Projections not working along with Data Loaders in HotChocolate v13 Graphql

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I am using EF Core in an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, these are the 2 entities in my domain:

1. Batch
2. Payments

This is how entities looks like :

```cs
public class Batch : IEntity
{
    public string InternalId { get; set; }
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    public List<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}

public class Payment : IEntity 
{
    public string InternalId { get; set; }
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I want to write a graphql query to return a Batch and its Payments.

I created 2 types ( Class Based)

```cs
public class Batch 
{
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    public int? PaymentsCount { get; set; }
    public decimal? TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public List<Payment> { get; set; }

    [DataLoader]
    internal static async Task<ILookup<string, Domain.PaymentBatch.PaymentBatch>> PaymentBatches(IReadOnlyList<string> keys,
        PaymentReadOnlyGraphQLContext paymentReadOnlyGraphQlContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var batches = await paymentReadOnlyGraphQlContext.PaymentBatches
            .Where(x => keys.Contains(x.TenantId))
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
        return batches.ToLookup(x=>x.TenantId)!;
    }
}

public class Payment 
{
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    // omitted other fields for brevity
}
```

Query :

```cs
public class BatchesQuery
{
    // Resolver
    [UsePaging(IncludeTotalCount = true)]
    [UseFiltering]
    [UseSorting]
    public async Task<List<Batch>> Batches(IPaymentBatchesDataLoader paymentBatchDataLoader, string tenantId, [Service] ILogger<BatchesQuery> logger)
    {
        try
        {
            var paymentBatches = await paymentBatchDataLoader.LoadAsync(tenantId, CancellationToken.None);
            return paymentBatches.Select(paymentBatch => new Batch()
                {
                    BatchId = paymentBatch.ExternalId,
                    PaymentsCount = paymentBatch.Payments,
                    TotalAmount = paymentBatch.Payments.SelectMany(x => x.RemittanceDetails).Sum(x => x.Net),
                    Payments = paymentBatch.PaymentRequests.Select(x => new Types.Payment()
                            {
                                Id = x.ExternalId,                              
                                Amount = x.RemittanceDetails.Sum(x => x.Net),
                            })
                            .ToList(),
                    TenantId = paymentBatch.TenantId
                })
                .ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.LogError(e, "Error getting batches");
            return new List<Batch>();
        }
    }
}
```

I created a Dataloader, query to fetch the data from the database. I expected the response will have the Batches along with the payments. For some reason the payments returned from the dataloaders are always null. I see batch data returned but not the payments.

I don't really understand what's happening. Am I missing anything in the setup ?

Should I create a Payment Query and Dataloader to get payments ?

Should I use Include statement in the batch dataloader like below ?

```cs
[DataLoader]
internal static async Task<ILookup<string, Domain.PaymentBatch.PaymentBatch>> PaymentBatches(IReadOnlyList<string> keys,
    PaymentReadOnlyGraphQLContext paymentReadOnlyGraphQlContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var batches = await paymentReadOnlyGraphQlContext.PaymentBatches
        .Where(x => keys.Contains(x.TenantId))
        .Include(b=>b.PaymentRequests)
        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
    return batches.ToLookup(x=>x.TenantId)!;
}
```

I used `[UseProjection]` annotation on the `BatchesQuery` but that didn't really help.

Could some please help me what I am missing ? I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72WVRPwzwLk to setup graphql in my API.

Comment: Normally when EF is working with projection and `IQueryable` it can dive through the navigation properties to ensure desired relationships are resolved without needing to eager load them. I am not familiar with this "query" pattern but it looks to be materializing each query so if you want related data you will need to eager load it.  I'm not sure what this pattern would offer over using EF's `IQueryable` and a compatible mapper.

Comment: If I eager load the relations, it is working, I am under assumption that if you use [UseProjection] annotation that loading is handled for you. the query pattern I am using is something described in the HotChocolate Dataloader pattern.

Comment: Projection in Hot Chocolate vs. EF accomplish the same thing, though I don't know if they integrate directly or not. Projection in EF requires working with it's `IQueryab;e<TEntity>`. As soon as your repository does a `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()` etc. then the projection is done code-side rather than DB-side meaning any related entities you want to include have to be eager loaded, or you need to enable lazy loading. (not recommended for projection scenarios)